# Show that an equivalence of categories between two $1$-object categories is an isomorphism.

Tags: category-theory

Suppose that $\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}$ are two categories with only $1$ object, and that there are functors $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}, G:\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{C}$ form an [equivalence of categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_categories#Definition).

**Question** Is it necessarily true that $FG=1_{\mathcal{D}}$ and $GF=1_{\mathcal{C}}$? If no, give a concrete (counter-)example.

**Attempt** I think the answer to the question is no. What I can show is that $F\widetilde{G}=1_\mathcal{D}, \widetilde{G}F=1_\mathcal{C}$, where $\widetilde{G}:\mathcal{D}\to \mathcal{C}$ is a "conjugate" of $G$. Could anyone provide a
counterexample/proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to note that your title question

> Show that an equivalence of categories between two 1-object categories is an isomorphism.

is different from the question in the body

> Question Is it necessarily true that $FG=1_D$ and $GF=1_C$? If no, give a concrete (counter-)example.

depending on exactly how you define "an equivalence of categories".

---

It is true that every functor between monoids $F: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ that forms part of an equivalence of categories is an isosmorphism. This is why the statement in the title of your question is often given as a fact.

It is false to claim that, whenever $F: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ and $G: \mathcal{D} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ are a pair of functors forming an equivalence, $G$ is the (strict) inverse of $F$. As you've shown, all we know is that $G$ is some conjugate of the inverse.

---

To get a concrete counterexample, take some nonabelian group (which we'll treat as the morphism set of our monoid). Let $F$ be the identity and $G$ be conjugation by some element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that an equivalence of categories is essentially surjective - see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0013 Lemma 4.2.19

Comment: Since both $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ have only $1$ object, any functor is (essentially) surjective. So I don't see why this property is helpful (in proving the claim)?